# Prove that on $(0, \pi/2]$, $\cot(x) < 1/x$

Tags: calculus, inequality

Simple question - Prove that on $(0, \pi/2]$,  $\cot(x) < 1/x$. Just trying to think of good ways to do this.

Comment: Is this statement true?

Comment: @JY1853 sorry typo, fixed it

Comment: Hint: it suffices to prove $\tan(x)>x$, which can be done with the Mean Value Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

For $x\in(0,\frac\pi2]$, one has
$$ 0<\int_0^xt\sin t\mathrm{d}t=-\int_0^xt\mathrm{d}\cos t=-x\cos x+\int_0^x\cos t\mathrm{d}t=-x\cos x+\sin x $$
which implies
$$ \cot x<\frac1x. $$

Answer (score 0):

Let $$f(x)=x \cos x-\sin x \implies f'(x)=-x \sin x <0, x\in (0,\pi/2]$$
So $f(x)$ is a decreasing function, so $x >0 \implies f(x) <f(0)=0 \implies x \cot x-1<0.$
Finally, $\implies  \cot x < \frac{1}{x}, ~if~ x \in (0,\pi/2]$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume without loss of generality that $x<\pi/2$. Take the radius-$\sqrt{2}$ circle of centre $O$, and two radii $OA,\,OB$ with $\langle AOB=x$. Extend $OB$ to meet at $C$ the tangent through $A$, so $\triangle OAC$ is of area $\tan x$. As it contains the sector between the radii, which has area $x$, $\tan x>x$.